# Adjusting the X zoom for the Shield UI Inversed Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I am using an Inversed Shield UI Chart  that I need to be able to zoom. I am using local data binding:

```
  var MyData = [
[0.75, 0.79],
[0.95, 1.03],
…
  ];

…
    dataSeries: [{
      seriesType: "rangebar",
      collectionAlias: "Series A",
      data: MyData
    }
```

and the chart actually works and displays data as expected.
Since some of the data values are much smaller than others, I need these bars to be zoomed in to and to stretch along the X axis. For that purpose I set the property:

```
zoomMode:'x',
```

but there is some strange result. It looks like bars zoom on the Y axis. What can be wrong to be getting this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue s quite simple. Since the chart is inversed this means that X and Y axes are switched. And so does the zoomMode scope. 
You need to set

```
zoomMode:’y’
```

in order to zoom the bars horizontally.